# ffmpeg resize: output format is lost

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to resize a video using ffmpeg, and it works just fine with most of the files, but one particular file is resized with huge quality loss (resolution is as requested, 1/2 of original one, but overall quality is like when streaming video on a modem like 33.6k in 1998).

Usually I'm using the

`ffmpeg -i video.vmw -vf "scale=iw/2:-1" video.vmw`

command, but in this case I'm trying to use this to avoid the quality drop:

`ffmpeg -i video.vmw -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -vf "scale=iw/2:-1" video-resized.avi`

Unfortunately, in the latter case mplayer then thinks it's rawvideo and then just doesn't show the video stream:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'video-resized.vmw':
  Metadata:
    copyright       : copyleft
    software        : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:01:50.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1622 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 960x540, 1520 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
  Stream #0:1: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 96 kb/s
```

While encoding however it shows that it properly codes the output streams:

```
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: MP@HL
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5275
    IsVBR           : 0
    copyright       : copyleft
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
```

I've tried to request other container types, such as mkv, but the result is identical.

The original file metadata is as follows:

```
Input #0, asf, from 'video.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: MP@HL
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5275
    IsVBR           : 0
    copyright       : copyleft
  Duration: 00:33:30.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8151 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 96 kb/s
  Stream #0:1(eng): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 8000 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[wmv3 @ 0x80641fe00] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
```